# Gallio, MBunit and WaTiN on .NET 4

Tags: .net-4.0, teamcity, watin, mbunit, gallio

I'm currently in the middle of upgrading out ASP.NET Application to .NET 4 Framework. The code compiles and our unit tests seem to run under the new .NET Framework without much problems. Our WaTiN tests however simply refuse to even start.

I've installed the Gallio 3.3 and 3.2 suites and neither succeeds in running the tests. 3.3 simply crashes when trying to discover the tests and 3.2 hangs when trying to execute the test. The output differs between the two versions, but bottomline is : neither work.

When looking at teamcity logs, I receive the following error output: http://pastebin.com/GNkQFfNr

This is with the latest version of both Watin and Gallio suite.
Has anyone been able to get this combination properly running under .NET4?

- Gallio : 3.3
- Watin : 2.1
- .NET : 4.0
- Buildagent : Windows XP 32bit
- invoked through nant scripts

Comment: Do they run outside of teamcity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT***
Editing the awnser as some people asked for the details:

We installed the latest version from Gallio. First we tried to build it from source, but this seemed to be failing for reason, so we took the installer to get the latest version installed. We also downloaded the no-install package and placed that inside our SVN.

We then downloaded the source from WaTiN and compiled this ourselves against the .NET 4 Framework. Awe also included the source and the binaries in our SVN so the build agents have access to this.

Finally we stripped out the NCover from Gallio, as this version was not .NET 4 Compatible. We replaced this with PartCover and updated the nant scripts to invoke PartCover instead of NCover.

Comment: Provide details, this is worse than useless. Not sure what's  stopping me from -1ing

Comment: updated the comment, the problem is that this config is machine specifici, so i can only give you a generic description

Comment: +1 Cool, at least it's not frustrating for someone to land on now (if you hadn't added this answer, you'd have been better off removing the question)